# Handling faiss-cpu vs. faiss-gpu in python setup script

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, faiss

I am trying write the setup script for my Python package which uses faiss such that an end user can install the CPU version of my package by default or specify a GPU-enabled version using `extras_require`. The problem is that faiss breaks if both `faiss-cpu` and `faiss-gpu` are simultaneously installed in the environment.

My setup script looks something like this:

```py
setup(
    ...
    install_requires=[
        "faiss-cpu==1.7.0",
        ...,
    ],
    extras_require=(
        "gpu": ["faiss-gpu==1.7.0", ...],
        ...,
    ),
)
```

Things work as expected when my package is installed with no extras, but if `[gpu]` is specified then both `faiss-cpu` and `faiss-gpu` are installed. The only way to resolve this is to manually uninstall both `faiss-cpu` and `faiss-gpu`, then reinstall `faiss-gpu` (interestingly, simply uninstalling `faiss-cpu` does not work).

How can I write or redesign my setup script to avoid this issue?

Comment: There is no any simple way. The only way is to put both in `extras_require` and document that a user must install either `package[cpu]` or `package[gpu]` but not both.